# pivot_longer: pattern based on column names as input

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a wide data frame with columns of the following pattern: `a1_var1`, `a2_var1`, `a3_var1`, `a1_var2`, `a2_var2`, `a3_var2`, etc. I want to pivot this to longer, creating a new variable named `a` that contains the values of the number behind the "a" (1, 2, 3) and for all values of `ax_var1` to be contained in the column `var1` (likewise for `var2`).

Consider this example data:

```
df <- data.frame(`id` = seq(1:3),
                 a1_var1 = c(111, 211, 311),
                 a2_var1 = c(121, 221, 321),
                 a3_var1 = c(131, 231, 331),
                 a1_var2 = c(112, 212, 312),
                 a2_var2 = c(122, 222, 322),
                 a3_var2 = c(132, 232, 332)) # first number is ID, second number is "a[x]" value, third number is var[x]
```

I would now like to transform the data to long format with the following columns: `id` (not unique per row anymore), `a` (containing the number from which the variable was taken, e.g. `a1_var2`: `a` = `1`), `var1` (containing all values from `ax_var1` columns, i.e. `x11`, `x21`, `x31`), and `var2` (containing all values from `ax_var2` columns, i.e. `x12`, `x22`, `x32`).

I want to achieve the following structure:

```
id   a   var1 var2
1    1    111  112
1    2    121  122
1    3    131  132
2    1    211  212
2    2    221  222
2    3    231  232
3    1    311  312
3    2    321  322
3    3    331  332
```

So far, I'm hard-coding this for every `varx` like this:

```
df %>% select(-c(ends_with("var2"))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("a1_var1", "a2_var1", "a3_var1"), names_to = "a", values_to = "var1") %>% 
  mutate(a=str_extract(a, "a\\d"),
         a=str_extract(a, "\\d"))
```

but since I have many varx columns, that's kind of bothersome - can someone point out a better way of achieving the above outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this in `pivot_longer` itself - i.e. specify the `names_to`as `c("a", ".value")` where 'a' will be column name of the prefix substring from the columns to be reshaped and `.value` represents the column values.  In the `names_pattern`, capture the substring of column name i.e. digits (`\\d+`) after the 'a' and the second capture group after the `_`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = c("a", ".value"), 
      names_pattern = "a(\\d+)_(.*)")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
     id a      var1  var2
  <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 1       111   112
2     1 2       121   122
3     1 3       131   132
4     2 1       211   212
5     2 2       221   222
6     2 3       231   232
7     3 1       311   312
8     3 2       321   322
9     3 3       331   332
```

Comment: thank you. Exactly what I was looking for! Just one thing: in my actual data, many rows of `a` end up being NA. I don't think it's a problem but more that the code creates also combinations where no data exists. Could you elaborate why this might be the case?

Comment: @Ivo that could be because one of the 'var' combination is not existing i.e. if you remove the last column, `df[-7] %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = c("a", ".value"), 
      names_pattern = "a(\\d+)_(.*)")` it returns NA for some values of 'var2'.  If both columns 'var1', 'var2' gets NA, it can be dropped with `values_drop_na = TRUE`